# A straight line homotopy connects invertible maps to invertible maps

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces and $T_i ∈ L(X, Y )$ for $i = 0, 1$ . Define
$T_t := (1 − t)T_0 + t T_1$ , $t ∈ [0, 1]$ and assume that there is a constant $c > 0$ such that $||x|| ≤ c ||T_tx||$ , $x ∈ X , t ∈ [0, 1]$ . How do we show that $T_1$ is a linear isomorphism iff $T_2$ is ?

A linear isomorphism is defined to be a bounded invertible linear map whose inverse is also bounded. Since we are working with Banach spaces, a bijection automatically means the inverse is also bounded. A hint was given to use the Banach fixed point theorem. Since that only applies for self mappings, I suspect we actually need to consider the map from $L(X, Y ) \to L(X, Y )$. So one idea is to prove the contrapositive, or contradiction. Because the space of invertible linear map with continuous inverse is actually an open set, we consider its complement which is closed and thus complete and try to apply Banach's fixed point theorem in this space. Assuming $T_1$ is not invertible, we want a contractive map on this space which converges to $T_2$ which will show that $T_2$ is also not invertible. However at the moment, I can't come up with such a mapping.

Comment: Usually behind these things there always is the Neumann series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumptions imply that all $T_t$ are injective, have closed range, and their inverses exists as operators from $R(T_t)$ to $X$ and are uniformly bounded, $\|T_t^{-1}\|_{\mathcal L( R(T_t),X)}\le c$.

It only needs to be shown that all $T_t$ are surjective if $T_0$ is surjective.

Take $t\in [0,1)$ such that $T_t$ is surjective. Take $s\in (t,1]$.
Then
$$
T_s =T_t + (T_s-T_t) = T_t + (s-t)(T_1-T_0).
$$
Take $y\in Y$. Then $y=T_s(x)$ is equivalent to
$$
 T_t^{-1}y =  x +  (s-t)T_t^{-1}(T_1-T_0)x
$$
and to the fixed point equation
$$
x = T_t^{-1}y  - (s-t)T_t^{-1}(T_1-T_0)x.
$$
Define $F(x) := T_t^{-1}y  - (s-t)T_t^{-1}(T_1-T_0)x$. Then
$$
\|F(x_1) - F(x_2) \| \le (s-t) c \|T_1-T_0\| \|x_1-x_2\| ,
$$
which is a contraction if $s-t< \frac1{c\|T_1-T_0\|}$.

This shows: if $T_t$ is surjective, then $T_s$ is surjective for all $s\in [t,t+\frac1{c\|T_1-T_0\|})$. After finitely many such steps we get that $T_1$ is surjective if $T_0$ is surjective.